# is it possible to split large parquet files into small files using Hadoop api?

Tags: java, hadoop, parquet

We have very large parquet files of size which are around of 100GB.

is it possible to divide the files into smaller files using hadoop api.

We are not using spark so can not split using spark apis.

I tried using hadoop aps but i do not see it working.

```
public class ParquetGeneratorDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Path path = new Path("parquet_data_" + ".parquet");
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
        fs.delete(path, false);

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            generateParquetFileFor();
        }
        System.out.println(fs.getFileStatus(path).getLen() / 1024);
        FileSplit split = new FileSplit(path, 0L, 512L, new String[]{});
        System.out.println(split.toString());

}
private static void generateParquetFileFor() {
    try {
        Schema schema = parseSchema();
        Path path = new Path("parquet_data_" + ".parquet");
        System.out.println(path.getName());
        FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
        List<GenericData.Record> recordList = generateRecords(schema);

        try (ParquetWriter<GenericData.Record> writer = AvroParquetWriter.<GenericData.Record>builder(path).withSchema(
                schema).withCompressionCodec(CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY).withRowGroupSize(ParquetWriter.DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE).withPageSize(
                ParquetWriter.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE).withConf(new Configuration()).withValidation(false).withDictionaryEncoding(false).build()) {

            for (GenericData.Record record : recordList) {
                writer.write(record);
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}


private static Schema parseSchema() {
    String schemaJson = "{\"namespace\": \"org.myorganization.mynamespace\"," //Not used in Parquet, can put anything
            + "\"type\": \"record\"," //Must be set as record
            + "\"name\": \"myrecordname\"," //Not used in Parquet, can put anything
            + "\"fields\": [" + " {\"name\": \"myString\",  \"type\": [\"string\", \"null\"]}" + ", {\"name\": \"myInteger\", \"type\": \"int\"}" //Required field
            + " ]}";

    Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser().setValidate(true);
    return parser.parse(schemaJson);
}

private static List<GenericData.Record> generateRecords(Schema schema) {

    List<GenericData.Record> recordList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 2048 * 1000; i++) {
        GenericData.Record record = new GenericData.Record(schema);
        record.put("myInteger", i);
        record.put("myString", i + " hi world of parquet!");
        recordList.add(record);
    }
    return recordList;
}
```

}

Comment: If you can use Hadoop dependencies, then you can use Spark